# Calculating Currents and Voltages in and AC RL Circuit provided below

Tags: ac, inductor

I am studying RL Circuits with AC sources. I am trying to solve this circuit

[image: AC RL Circuit]

So far, I am only able to calculate the current *iL* through the inductor as for the other parts I can't grasp the concepts. It is not a homework question so please elaborate it. 
My working so far:

[image]
And I intend to solve this circuit using time-domain analysis not by converting it to frequency-domain.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Where do you think Thevanin's theorem would be most helpful?  Are you familiar with phasors for AC analysis?  What's the impedance of the inductor at the given frequency?  If you can think through these things you should be able to make a try at solving the problem.  If you get stuck on specifics show your work and update your question.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Don't trip over your brain on this. Separate R from L. A resistor has only resistance, the same (ideally) at all frequencies. Figure out the impedance of L and treat it as a resistor in parallel with R. `Use Thevenin's theorem` tells you what to do.

Comment: @JohnD I am familiar with Phasors and also with Impedance but the thing is that i intend to solve this problem without using complex analysis. I'll be updating my question by providing my working so far.